# How can I get data from two tables using one REST URL?

Tags: mysql, rest, sails.js

I've been reading up on the Sails JS docs but I can't really figure it out.

I have two tables, X and Y. When I shoot a GET request at localhost:1337/xydata I want to receive the results of the following SELECT query:

```
SELECT x.id, x.info, y.name
FROM x, y
WHERE y.xId = x.id
```

(note that this is just an example)

How would I accomplish this? Controllers seem to only give me one table at a time, am I looking in the wrong place?

Comment: Are you relying on [Blueprints](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/blueprints) for this? You'll have to write controller code.

Comment: I am currently using blueprints for a couple of other controllers, yes

Comment: Here your requirement of getting data from 2 tables is not supported in blueprints. So, you'll have to write your own controller code.

Comment: So I'd have to make a controller that executes the select query as raw SQL, then returns that in JSON, correct?

Comment: Yes, either raw SQL or if you have these 2 models [associated](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/associations) in Sails you can use Waterline ORM with [`.populate()`](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/populated-values)

Comment: @Sangharsh Thanks!

Comment: @Sangharsh you should post your suggestions as an answer so that the OP can accept it and this question can be marked as answered!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Blueprints](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/blueprints) are great for prototyping a model's CRUD APIs quickly

However, while building any reasonably complex application, some of your requirements will not be covered by Blueprints. In such cases, a **custom controller action** should be implemented.

In this case, you can either use raw SQL or Waterline ORM with [.populate()](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/populated-values)
 (if you have these 2 models associated in Sails)